Biblatex: Create the in-text reference again before every item in bibliography
My goal is to achieve the following output in my bibliography:
Teixeira et al. 2022

   Teixeira, E. L. S., B. Tjahjono, M. Beltran and J. Julião. 2022. Demystifying
   the digital transition of remanufacturing: A systematic review of literature.
   Computers in Industry 134:p. 103567.

The idea is to have the reference as it appears in the text to be also printed in the bibliography. I am currently using biblatex-chicago like the following:
\usepackage[authordate,
giveninits,
natbib,
maxnames=3,
minnames=1,
maxbibnames=10,
minbibnames=7,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

My current approach is the the following:
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \textcite{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \newline % Add a line break after the citation
  \newunit\newblock
}

This does the majority of the trick, but for some reason it ignores everything related to the max author names... So the generated output is like this:
Teixeira, Tjahjono, Beltran and Julião (2022)
   Teixeira, E. L. S., B. Tjahjono, M. Beltran and J. Julião. 2022. Demystifying
   the digital transition of remanufacturing: A systematic review of literature.
   Computers in Industry 134:p. 103567

Maybe there is some expert for biblatex to know a method to achieve this?
Best regards
Full example:
\documentclass{article}

% Load biblatex-chicago package with specific options
\usepackage[authordate,
    giveninits,
    natbib,
    maxnames=3,
    minnames=1,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=10,
    minbibnames=7,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Teixeira2022,
  author    = {Teixeira, E. L. S. and Tjahjono, B. and Beltran, M. and Julião, J.},
  title     = {Demystifying the digital transition of remanufacturing: A systematic review of literature.},
  journal   = {Computers in Industry},
  volume    = {134},
  pages     = {103567},
  year      = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents}

% Load the generated .bib file
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \textcite{\thefield{entrykey}} % Automatically generate the citation style (Author et al., Year)
    \newline
    \newunit\newblock
}

\begin{document}

% Example citation in the text
According to \textcite{Teixeira2022}, remanufacturing is crucial in the digital transition.

% Print the bibliography
\printbibliography

\end{document}


Please add a compilable [mre] to your question

added an example

I am not sure how the migration works, but I could also just simply create the question in this forum if the chance of finding some expert is higher
